# Connecting to RDS from PHP does not work, but works from console

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently set up RDS server using MySQL dataset and using EC2 beanstalk as a server.

I have been able to connect to dataset from

1. console of local machine using endpoint url, username, password
2. from PHP on local machine, using following code:

   ```
   $servername = "xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
   $username = "xxxxx";
   $password = "xxxxxxx";
   $dbname = "xxxxxxx";

   // Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
   // Check connection
   if (! $conn) {
       echo "not connecting..!!";
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
   }
   ```

This works correctly, inserts data into the database in the RDS.

3. I `ssh` to EC2, check connect from console (using mysql -h  -u  -p). This too, work correctly. I can change the database from here and it is indeed reflected.

Next, I deploy the exact same code on EC2, and hope it works via PHP as well, as that code is already tested. But it does not.

I checked SELinux status is `disabled`

What else could be a problem?

I should mention: I am using Amazon Linux, I installed 'httpd' on local it.

Comment: Is `mysqli` present in your PHP configuration on the EC2 instance? `phpinfo();`

Comment: You show PHP code that should output `mysqli_error()` if the connection fails. What is the error it outputs? Note it might be output in your httpd error log, as PHP errors usually are.

Comment: @Scuzzy, `mysqli` is available. php version is 7.0.21.

Comment: @BillKarwin, there is a blank page, no error is printed, I wonder why. It does not even print echo msg - "not connecting..!!", neither the echo message I put just after the if(! $conn)

Comment: @Adorn, Always check your httpd error log. In fact, just leave a window open doing `tail -f` on the error log while you are testing PHP code. You might have a fatal PHP error that prevents the script from executing at all. Why are PHP developers not taught this on their first day?!?

Comment: @BillKarwin you are right, I had not installed `php-mysqli`. This is how "seasonal" web developers learn the standard ways of doing the things

Comment: @Adorn, Another tricky situation with PHP is that a server can use one php.ini for command-line usage, but a different php.ini (perhaps loading different extensions) for httpd usage. So to be sure, use `phpinfo()` in a PHP script you call via web page request. The output of `phpinfo()` should report which php.ini it used. Also remember every time you edit php.ini, you need to restart your http server.

Comment: One thing you neglected was describing the error. There's many facets in a PHP scripts execution that it could be almost anything at any level of the solution stack :)